# What is "NrbReleaseSearch Feature"?

Tags: search, feature

I cannot find the answer to what this feature is... I'm using SharePoint 2010 and this is in the "site settings">"site collection features" menu where this is one of several things you can activate/deactivate. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SharePoint built in feature called "**NrbReleaseSearch** Feature". My guess is that it is some custom feature deployed to your site. You can see this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10437.sharepoint-2010-existing-features-guid.aspx) to see a list of all the built in features of SP 2010.

Comment: Makes sense; that would explain why I couldn't find anything about it! Thanks!